# Can't run npm install in an Ember CLI application?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

I am setting up an Ember application on a new laptop. I installed node, npm through brew and I also have the Ember CLI. Within the Ember CLI app, I'm trying to do an `npm install` but when I do, I get this error in the terminal:

```
npm WARN package.json npm@1.4.21 Non-dependency in bundleDependencies: inherits
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.11
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: expresss
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'expresss' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'ember-cli'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Nagarjun/Code/sumo-list/web-client/npm-debug.log
```

I can't run my projects until this is resolved. What am I missing? I even Googled but couldn't find anything for *expresss*.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is 'expresss' (with an extra s) is a package on npm that was pulled. The dependency was in fact listed in the package.json file for ember-cli but I don't think anyone ever noticed it until later versions.

Proof: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/blob/ec8a6ab898599746bddbb8f72f7633c29f0ee95b/package.json#L58

Comment: You're right! However, when I do an ack across my system to find the word "expresss", it doesn't show up anywhere. Only once, it did show up on a package.json file. See https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2723#issuecomment-66706275. I'm confused as to how I could have a 0.4 package.json on my new laptop with the latest versions of node and npm. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by uninstalling node and npm completely using brew. Then, installing node.js using the package from nodejs.org. Now, my npm version is 1.4.28. Looks like the issue was caused by the newer npm 2.1.10. Not sure why brew automatically picks up the new npm.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your package.json dependencies section. Looks like a typo.

Comment: My package.json doesn't have any string for 'expresss'. This is the only thing I have `"express": "^4.1.1",`.

Comment: Did you look inside the ember-cli package.json too?

Comment: I actually did an ack for the entire folder for the word "expresss" and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but it got fixed by running sudo npm install -g ember-cli